# Remove Image Exif and adjust orientation in Angular or JS?

Tags: javascript, angular, exif

When a user selects an image I am trying to implement as solution to fix the EXIF orientation and then remove the EXIF so it uploads to my file server in the correct orientation without the meta data.

So far the solutions I have found is for preview files only. I am hoping if some can show me how I could implement this solution either in Javascript or Angular?

My very basic file input is as follows:

fileEvent(ev: any): void {
let obj = ev.target.files[0];
}
Thanks so much in advance,

Answer (score 0):

There are a few very cool TIFF decoder libraries in existence, but AFAIK, there aren't any that would allow you to modify the EXIF tags.  This operation is MUCH better suited for the backend where (depending upon your backend source language) there are many more libraries available that can help you.